Equivalence of Definitions of Countable Set in ZF
Definition 1: $S$ is countable if and only if there exists an injection: $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$
Definition 2: $S$ is countable if and only if it is finite or there exists a bijection $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$.
It is easy to prove that Definition 2 implies Definition 1. In ZF without the axiom of countable choice, it is generally not possible to prove that Definition 1 implies Definition 2. Without the axiom of countable choice (AC), there may exist sets for which an injection $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ exists, but a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be explicitly constructed.
Which definition of countability is correct in ZF? Let’s take a step back and consider the definition of a finite set: sets can be finite or Dedekind finite. These definitions are equivalent in ZFC but not in ZF. However, there is no issue here because the two concepts have distinct names. But when we state in ZF that a set is countable, what do we actually mean? Do we refer to Definition 1 or Definition 2?
As with finiteness, where finite and Dedekind finite are distinguished, ideally, separate terms would be used to describe sets satisfying Definition 1 and Definition 2. However, such terminology is rarely adopted, leading to potential confusion.
Let us consider a specific example of such ambiguity. Let $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ be a surjection. Can it be proven that the set $S$ is countable in the sense of Definition 2? In ZF, the existence of a surjection $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ does not imply that $S$ is countable in the sense of Definition 2. The transition from a surjection to a bijection requires the axiom of countable choice.
Suppose that the Axiom of Countable Choice for Finite Sets holds. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a countable set of non-empty finite sets. We want to prove that the union of any countable set of finite sets is countable. At this point, a fork arises, and the structure of the proof depends on which of the two definitions of countability we adopt. If we only accept the second definition of countability, then, according to proofwiki.org, we will encounter the existence of a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \bigcup \mathcal{F}$. At this point, proofwiki finishes the proof, but in our case, to fully complete it, the Axiom of Countable Choice is required. However, if we adopt the Axiom of Countable Choice, then the Axiom of Countable Choice for finite sets loses any meaning for us, as we have already assumed a stronger statement. This leads to a vicious circle, where the weaker statement requires the stronger statement to fully complete the proof.
My original goal was to prove the theorem on the equivalence of $\mathrm{AC_{finite}}$​ and the countability of the union of a countable family of finite sets (in the strict sense of countability). I encountered the problem described above. Does such a proof exist? Are there other sources, apart from proofwiki.org, that I could use?

The two definitions are equivalent, as well as "$A$ is empty or there is a surjection from $\Bbb N$ onto $A$". All without choice.
The reason, of course, is that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered, so we can use this well-ordering to define our choices explicitly: pick the smallest thing that 'works' (in context).
So, for example, if there is an injection from $A$ to $\Bbb N$, and $A$ is infinite, then there is a bijection between $A$ and some $B\subseteq\Bbb N$ which is infinite. Now, we can just find a bijection between $B$ and $\Bbb N$ and compose those.
Recursively, we can map $\min B$ to $0$, then the next one to $1$, etc. So the $n$th member of $B$ is mapped to $n$. No choice is involved here, since we are simply going through the well-ordering of $\Bbb N$, or rather its restriction to $B$, one step at a time. Easily, this is an injection, but it is also a surjection, since $B$ is infinite. Note, by the way, that this is the standard proof in the context of $\sf ZFC$ that is used in freshman year classes, well before the Axiom of Choice is even mentioned. Simply because it is not needed. Can we come up with some contrived notion of countability that requires some semblance of the Axiom of Choice to be equivalent to the standard one? Yes. We could. Do any of the standard equivalences require the Axiom of Choice? No. They do not.
Your suggestion that a surjection from $S$ onto $\Bbb N$ might imply that $S$ is countable has nothing to do with the Axiom of Choice. $\Bbb R$ maps onto $\Bbb N$. Quite easily. Does that mean that the set of real numbers is countable? No. It does not. But if $\Bbb N$ maps onto $S$, then $S$ is in fact countable. So, $\Bbb N$ does not surject onto $\Bbb R$.
